# How to use Unix command line utils to filter fields from a json record?

Tags: json, unix, command-line, grep

I have a text file with many json records in a similar format to the following:

```
{"foo":"1","bar":"2","baz":"1","fu":"1"}
{"foo":"3","bar":"2","baz":"4","fu":"2","barf":"1"}
{"foo":"2","bar":"4","baz":"5","fu":"3"}
{"foo":"5","blerg":"1","bar":"6","baz":"6","fu":"7"}
```

How can I use standard unix command line utils to filter out more than one non adjacent field?

Ex. say I want to select only bar and fu, I would want my output to look like:

```
"bar":"2" "fu":"1"
```

...or something along those lines. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the point of using complex regex to fetch something that a JSON parser would get immediately. `grep` is not suited for this, maybe `sed` is better.

Comment: Open to pretty much anything - I am limited to pretty much any of the standard CLI tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed` you can do this:

```
$ sed -r 's/.*("bar":"\w*").*("fu":"\w*").*/\1 \2/' file
"bar":"2" "fu":"1"
"bar":"2" "fu":"2"
"bar":"4" "fu":"3"
"bar":"6" "fu":"7"
```

As you can see, `.*("bar":"\w*").*("fu":"\w*").*` catches the blocks of `"bar": "value"` and `"fu": "value"` and prints them back with `\1` and `\2`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple job for `awk`

```
awk -F"[{},]" '{print $3,$5}' file
"bar":"2" "fu":"1"
"bar":"2" "fu":"2"
"bar":"4" "fu":"3"
"bar":"6" "fu":"7"
```

An `awk` that support random fields:

```
awk -F, '{gsub(/[{}]/,x);for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/"foo"|"bar"/) printf "%s ",$i;print ""}' file
"foo":"1" "bar":"2"
"foo":"3" "bar":"2"
"foo":"2" "bar":"4"
"foo":"5" "bar":"6"
```

Comment: Should have been more clear with the question - unfortunately the number of fields is arbitrary

Answer (score 1):

If the json format is fixed, you can use `sed` and `cut` to filter out particular columns. For example, if you want to filter out the 2nd and the 4th columns, you can run:

```
$ cat output.txt | sed s/[{}]//g | cut -d, -f2,4 | sed s/,/" "/g
```

If you want to be more flexible, you can run `sed with a ***proper*** regular expression or write a python script, which will be pretty much easier.

**Update:** Thanks for pointing out a potential performance issue. Anyway, I vote for the `awk` solution.

```
$ sed s/[{}]//g output.txt | cut -d, -f2,4 | sed s/,/" "/g
```

Comment: You should never `cat`data to other program that can read data itself. `sed s/[{}]//g file | cut -d, -f2,4 | sed s/,/" "/g`

Answer (score 1):

Fur future comers, I think json-specific parsers like [json](https://github.com/trentm/json) command-line tool would be the cleanest solution. The bottom of the readme page there has a few references to alternatives as well